# Pandas Issue using user_agent attribute on column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use some of the attributes like `user_agent.is_pc` from https://github.com/selwin/python-user-agents .  But I am running into an issue when I try to use one.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from user_agents import parse

d = {'uas': ['Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; wbx 1.0.0; Zoom 3.6.0; ms-office; MSOffice 16)', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko','SEP/14.2.1023.0100, MID/{9BA868A4-903E-0DC4-5A76-A4A1EACEF17F}, SID/4 LUE/2.6.1.11 (Windows;10.0;SP0.0;X64;ENU)']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df
    uas                                                 
0   Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT ...   
1   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7....   
2   SEP/14.2.1023.0100, MID/{9BA868A4-903E-0DC4-5A...
```

I add parse the useragent string and create a new column:

```
'''PARSE THE USER AGENT STRINGS'''
df['parsed'] = df['uas'].apply(lambda ua: parse(ua))

    uas                                                 parsed
0   Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT ...   PC / Windows 7 / IE 11.0
1   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7....   PC / Windows 7 / IE 11.0
2   SEP/14.2.1023.0100, MID/{9BA868A4-903E-0DC4-5A...   Other / Windows / Other
```

Now I would like to create a new column the returns a boolean for `is_pc`

```
df['pc'] = df['parsed'].apply(lambda ua: is_pc(ua))
```

but this gives me the error:
`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'is_pc'`

This works fine when I just use it on one user agent string:

```
ua_string = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; wbx 1.0.0; Zoom 3.6.0; ms-office; MSOffice 16)'
user_agent = parse(ua_string)
user_agent.is_pc
```

Output:

```
user_agent.is_pc
True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling `is_pc` correctly in the apply function.  `is_pc` is a method of `user_agent.parse`, not a function that accepts `pd.Series`. This should work

```
df['pc'] = df['parsed'].apply(lambda ua: ua.is_pc)
```

Returns:

```
                                                 uas  ...       pc
0  Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT ...  ...     True
1  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7....  ...     True
2  SEP/14.2.1023.0100, MID/{9BA868A4-903E-0DC4-5A...  ...    False
```

Comment: I see where I went wrong. Thank you so much @dubbbdan